# Save file in server - React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `file-saver.saveAs(Blob,  filename)` to download a file to client's system, in React.js,

I run the server, where the ip address is localhost:3000

I have a doubt, Is it possible to save a file in public folder, when the client press the save button?

Thanks

Comment: no, the client can not access the servers file system (in your case the react dev-server). If you want to save files on the backend you need to spin up your own server. Look into node.js since you can write you backend code in javascript wich you probably already know.

Comment: @JannisMorgenstern, thanks for writing, Actually, if the client pressed the save button, then I want the file to be saved in the public folder or any other folder in the server, Is it possible?

Comment: like I said, you would have to implement your own server. When you start your react apllication, react-scripts will spin up a webpack-development-server. You can not save files to that.

Comment: @JannisMorgenstern, thanks, I understand